# Row_Number() function not working in sqlite version 3.5.1

Tags: sqlite

I have an SQLite 3.5.1 version.

I would like to know how to use `Row_Number()` function in SQLite.
I have tried below query in version 3.5.1 but its mot working and its shows an error message:

> "21-11-2020 10:11:05: SQL Error: near "(": syntax error  <Select *,
> ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY IdNo) AS NoId from LibraryFolder">

```
Select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY IdNo) AS NoId
from LibraryFolder
```

Answer (score 2):

Your version of SQLite does not support window functions which were introduced in version 3.25.0.

Another way to do what you want is this:

```
SELECT t.*, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LibraryFolder WHERE IdNo <= t.IdNo) AS NoId
FROM LibraryFolder AS t
```

If `IdNo` is not unique, then you need additional conditions, including the use of the column `rowid` to define the order:

```
SELECT t.*, 
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 
    FROM LibraryFolder 
    WHERE IdNo < t.IdNo OR (IdNo = t.IdNo AND ROWID < t.ROWID)
  ) AS NoId
FROM LibraryFolder AS t
```